# Tesseract 3.05 : Failed loading language `eng` when training Chinese

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract to train a Chinese model, here's my script:

`./tesstrain.sh \
  --lang chi_sim 
  --langdata_dir ../../langdata 
  --tessdata_dir ../    # root directory of tesseract
  --output_dir ../../output`

At the first, everything works fine, but when it comes to `phase E: Extracting features`, something went wrong:

`Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Couldn't initialize tesseract`

I don't understand, I am trying to train a Chinese model, why it comes to look for `eng` language, and how do I resolve this problem? thanks!